# Test case after one day in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following is my code.   When I recorded it and ran it in eclipse, it was initially successful; but after one day I ran the same test case, and now it fails.  Suggest to me what and where to modify my test so it will run properly.

```
   package testing;

        import java.util.regex.Pattern;
        import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

        import org.junit.*;

        import static org.junit.Assert.*;
        import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

        import org.openqa.selenium.*;
        import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

        public class Men_Testing {
          private WebDriver driver;
          private String baseUrl;
          private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
          private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

          @Before
          public void setUp() throws Exception {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseUrl = "http://staging.vfitshoes.com/";
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          }

          @Test
          public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
            driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.doright > a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("8803477");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign-In")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#category > li > a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("dolist")).click();
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select-sort"))).selectByVisibleText("Price Low To High");
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select-sort"))).selectByVisibleText("Price High To Low");
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select-sort"))).selectByVisibleText("Shoe Name A to Z");
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select-sort"))).selectByVisibleText("Shoe Name Z to A");
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("no-on-page"))).selectByVisibleText("40");
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("no-on-page"))).selectByVisibleText("60");
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("no-on-page"))).selectByVisibleText("100");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pagination-data']/ul/li[3]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("3")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pagination-data']/ul/li[6]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pagination-data']/ul/li")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.control-btn.paginate-no")).click();
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("no-on-page"))).selectByVisibleText("20");
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select-sort"))).selectByVisibleText("VFit First");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.slideThree > label")).click();

            driver.get(baseUrl + "/shoes_all_view.jsp?so=-4&pn=1&g=1&style=%25|Sneakers%20%26%20Athletic%20Shoes");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Athletic & Sneakers")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
           // new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("variant_id"))).selectByVisibleText("Black/Charcoal/True Red");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/4/8/3/9/2548398-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("variant_id"))).selectByVisibleText("Gray/Coral/Black");
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("variant_id"))).selectByVisibleText("Dress Blues/Gum");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/4/5/4/5/9/2454597-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("variant_id"))).selectByVisibleText("Khaki/Black");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/0/8/5/2/2508529-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/4/1/4/5/5/2414557-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/1/6/4/3/2516433-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/8/5/1/4/9/1851491-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/1/0/3/9/2510393-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/0/6/4/9/2/1064923-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/4/8/3/3/2548338-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/4/0/5/4/9/2405496-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();

            driver.get(baseUrl + "/shoes_all_view.jsp?so=-4&pn=1&g=1&style=%25|Sneakers%20%26%20Athletic%20Shoes");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Boots")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("variant_id"))).selectByVisibleText("Dark Brown");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a > img")).click();
            // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [waitForPopUp | _blank | 30000]]

            driver.get(baseUrl + "/shoes_all_view.jsp?so=-4&pn=1&g=1&style=%25|Boots");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/1/1/5/5/1/2115515-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/2/2/6/7/7/2226774-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/6/3/6/5/1/163651-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/4/6/2/5/8/2462587-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/0/8/8/4/2/2088423-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/4/6/8/4/3/2468435-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/7/8/6/6/3/2786632-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();

            driver.get(baseUrl + "/shoes_all_view.jsp?so=-4&pn=1&g=1&style=%25|Boots");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Boat Shoes")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("variant_id"))).selectByVisibleText("Dark Tan");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/2/7/6/3/0/2276308-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("variant_id"))).selectByVisibleText("Black");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/3/6/5/3/4/1365346-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/2/6/9/3/2/2269328-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/0/7/9/6/6/2079660-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/1/9/3/2/2519326-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/1/8/8/6/2518864-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Climbing")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("variant_id"))).selectByVisibleText("Green/Blue");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/3/1/4/4/3/131443-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/7/8/1/2/1/1781215-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/749/7493102/1396-802332-t.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Clogs & Mules")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/6/5/5/6/4/2655641-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/6/4/5/5/9/2645591-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/2/5/3/5/2325356-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/4/8/2/2/2548225-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Hiking & Camping")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/5/5/3/5/2355351-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Loafers")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/7/1/5/7/7/1715774-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/5/9/9/4/2359946-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/9/7/9/4/2597940-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/4/7/5/9/3/2475933-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Oxfords")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/9/0/9/2/2390927-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/0/0/3/6/2300368-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/8/8/0/1/5/1880151-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/9/0/9/2/2390925-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/6/6/1/4/4/2661447-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sandals")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("variant_id"))).selectByVisibleText("Light Brown");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/5/5/8/0/5/1558057-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/1/3/7/3/2513738-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/1/2/7/3/9/2127398-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/6/1/0/0/9/2610095-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/2/3/8/2/8/2238287-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Snowboarding")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/1/7/9/5/2317951-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/1/7/9/5/2317953-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/1/0/6/3/2310639-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/9/0/2/0/5/1902057-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/2/7/1/7/8/2271786-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/2/0/9/1/2320913-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Slippers")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image-small")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/1/7/0/1/4/1170149-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/3/6/9/7/0/2369706-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/8/7/5/7/1/287571-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/732/7329251/7769-440855-t.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/9/7/2/9720-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/6/6/7/1/1/5/667115-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/3/6/0/36061-p-DETAILED.jpg')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back to Previous Page")).click();


          }

          @After
          public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            driver.quit();
            String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
            if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
              fail(verificationErrorString);
            }
          }

          private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
            try {
              driver.findElement(by);
              return true;
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
              return false;
            }
          }

          private boolean isAlertPresent() {
            try {
              driver.switchTo().alert();
              return true;
            } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
              return false;
            }
          }

          private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
            try {
              Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
              String alertText = alert.getText();
              if (acceptNextAlert) {
                alert.accept();
              } else {
                alert.dismiss();
              }
              return alertText;
            } finally {
              acceptNextAlert = true;
            }
          }
        }
```

I have even used Thread.sleep, but it still is failing.  I am using 'selenium Ide 2.5.0' and 'selenium-2.41.0' jar file and Firefox 28.0.  When running it gives this Error.  Please tell me what to add extra in my code to get it to run properly.

```
       org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/5/4/8/0/2554809-p-DETAILED.jpg')]"}
Command duration or timeout: 31.78 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'hp', ip: '192.168.1.103', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: d9828113-feb8-4959-87ab-8a8e920a219b
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=28.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:445)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:357)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
    at kids_select.Kids_selection.testUntitled(Kids_selection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[contains(@src,'http://www.zappos.com/images/z/2/5/5/4/8/0/2554809-p-DETAILED.jpg')]"}
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'hp', ip: '192.168.1.103', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/n207tu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1446138331564365903webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8905)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/n207tu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1446138331564365903webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:396)
```

Comment: I notice you are running the FirefoxDriver, therefore I suspect that it is due to an automatic upgrade of Firefox. Provide more information - what Selenium & Firefox versions you are using? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I would second what Arran said but offer an alternative possibility to investigate.  Is it possible that the data results changed on the site you are on between today and yesterday.  This could account for the link no longer being found.